# Какую сортировку использует AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, сортировка, angularjs

Есть массив с именами:

```
Петров, Иванов, Пользователь 1, Пользователь 2, ..., Пользователь 11, ..., Пользователь 21, ...
```

Почему-то когда я сортирую (при помощи AngularJS), получаю ответ:

```
Иванов
Петров
Пользователь 1
Пользователь 11
Пользователь 2
Пользователь 22
...
```

Я вот не пойму - что это за сортировка такая? *Пользователь 11* должен же быть после *Пользователя 2* и вообще после Петрова.

Как сделать так, чтобы сортировалось правильно?

Comment: Если сранвивать строки побайтово, что наверняка и делает angular, строка с символом 1 всегда будет меньше строки с символом 2 в той же позиции и с тем же префиксом.

Comment: 1. __Пользователь 11_ и так идёт после _Петрова_. 2. В лексикографическом порядке (строки ведь сортируются, а не числа) _Пользователь 11_ идёт раньше, чем _Пользователь 2_. 3. Откуда вообще взялся _Сидоров_? Вот он единственный, кто не к месту здесь.

Comment: Да- про Сидорова- то я ошибся. Вообщем всё нормально работает. То у меня глюк))) Хотел, что б Пользователь 10 был после Пользователь 9. .

Comment: Хитрых приёмов с сортировкой _Пользователь 9_ перед _Пользователь 10_ не знаю, могу лишь посоветовать вручную правила сортировки написать.

Comment: Чтобы "Пользователь 10" был после "Пользователь 9", нужно добавить второй пробел или ноль перед девяткой в "Пользователь 9". Т.е. это вопрос подготовки данных. Вероятно, можно написать функцию сортировки, которая в случае, если оба аргумента будут "Пользователь " и число, будет сравнивать числа, в остальных случаях строки целиком.